# Krull dimension of affine $\Bbbk$-algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Given an ideal, $\mathfrak{a} = \langle x_2x_3 \rangle \subseteq \Bbbk[x_1, x_2,x_3]$, where $\Bbbk$ is a field. We have that the maximal set of indeterminates independent modulo the ideal $\mathfrak{a}$, $\{x_1,x_2\}$, is of cardinality 2. Therefore the dimension of $\Bbbk[x_1,x_2,x_3]/\mathfrak{a}$ is 2. I am not able to find a maximal chain of prime ideals of length 2. Can someone help me construct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about $(x_3)/\mathfrak a\subsetneq(x_2,x_3)/\mathfrak a\subsetneq(x_1,x_2,x_3)/\mathfrak a$?

Comment: how do you show they are prime in the quotient ring?

Comment: and the chain you have given is of length 3? Also isnt the first element (0)?

Comment: the reason why i am asking how they are prime is because I would like to know how you thought of the construction so that for another example, say if the ideal is $\mathfrak{a} = <x_1, x_2>$ i can construct a chain. I understand $(x_2x_3)$ is zero in the factor ring but I still dont understand how the chain is of length 2 in the factor ring. Thanks for the help so far but it would be great if you could explain further.

Comment: isnt the chain in the factor ring the following : $(\overline{0}) \subsetneq (\overline{x_3}) \subseteq (\overline{x_2}, \overline{x_3}) \subseteq (\overline{x_1}, \overline{x_2},\overline{x_3})$

Comment: Yes, it is, but please remove $(\overline 0)$: in your quotient ring it is not prime! The chain of primes starts with $(\overline{x_3})$.